# Cannot have a zero-length USB "serial" string descriptor?

Tags: windows, usb

I am working on a USB hardware project, and would like the user to be able to change the device serial number. This is reported to the system via "USB string descriptor" 3.

I find that if the serial is zero-length (and therefore 32 bytes of nulls), the device **doesn't even show up** in (Windows) Device Manager. Whereas when it has a non-zero number of (unicode) characters followed by nulls, it works fine.

Is there any particular reason why this should be the case?

Comment: 32 bytes of nulls is not a zero-length string but an invalid string. USB string descriptors are not null terminated. Instead, they contain the length (in bytes) as the first byte, then the descriptor type and finally as many UTF-16 code units as needed. So string descriptors are of variable length. A zero-length string descriptor is 2 bytes long: 0x02 0x03.

Comment: Hmm....now, on the one hand I *am* sending the string length-prefixed, I just neglected to mention this in the question. But on the other hand, I'm **always sending a fixed length**, irrespective of the *actual* length of the string. Which is probably the cause of the issue. Thank you! If you would like to make this an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It's odd that it works fine with strings that aren't zero-length though. I guess it's just random chance that sending a one-char string with a 30-char length prefix "happens to work".

Comment: Since Windows isn't open source, it's hard to guess about why it might or might not have bugs in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serial number is transmitted as the response to a control transfer request from the host and has the format of a string descriptor, which looks like so:

```
Offset  Field            Size   Description
0       bLength          1      Size of descriptor (in bytes)
1       bDescriptorType  1      String descriptor type (0x03)
2       bString          n      Unicode encoded string (in UTF-16)
```

The string descriptor has a variable length. The *bString* field starting at offset 2 is as long as required. The string is not null-terminated.

The string descriptor and thus the control transfer response for an empty string would look like so:

```
0x02 0x03
```

In any case, an empty or missing serial number isn't a good idea. Most operating systems use the combination of VID, PID and serial number to uniquely identify USB devices. On Windows, it's even the basis for driver installation though Windows has a few tricks to deal with a missing serial number.

To hear that the fixed length strings have worked on Windows, is a bit of a surprise. You cannot assume that it will work on other operation systems or even with a future Windows version.

Comment: Yes, I was sending a length of 32, but the string was smaller than 12 characters. And yet it worked, except when the string was all NULLs.

Comment: I realise that it is not recommended to omit the serial number, and during normal operation my device will have one.